# Plastic SCM MySQL Setup

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, plasticscm

After fresh installs of Plastic SCM and MySQL, I try to change the database backend to MySQL but consistently get the following error.

```
The database rep_1 can't be created. Check the server log (plastic.server.log). Error: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.   at Codice.CM.Data.BaseDataManager.CreateSingleRepository(Int64 repId)
   at admintool.DatabaseCopier.Start()
   at admintool.DatabaseMigrator.MigrateDatabases()
   at admintool.DatabaseMigrator.Start()
```

Any ideas? How can I set up MySWL or SQL Server? I have Sqlite working but need to switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your MySQL installation is throwing a timeout exception, some ideas:

- Is the access granted for the user you specified???
- Try changing the server name for an IP (Sometime the DNS can do ugly thing), or if you specified an IP or localhost try specifying the machine name.
- Review the server log to get more info (plasticd.log.txt)

If you want to try MySQL or SqlServer you can follow the following tutorials, it's very easy, it doens't use the Plastic SCM admin tool but it's more powerfull since you can specify more parameters:

- **SqlServer**: https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/administration/plastic-scm-version-control-administrator-guide.shtml#ConfigurePlasticSCMwithMSSQLServer
- **MySQL**: https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/administration/plastic-scm-version-control-administrator-guide.shtml#ConfigurePlasticSCMwithMySQL

Going back to your problem, you can try the following, I guess that your db.conf file (inside the Plastic SCM server directory) is now trying to connect to MySQL (check it by opening it and reviewing the provider tag), then try to start the server in console mode, in order to do it, open an admin command line window, cd to the Plastic SCM server directory and type:

"plasticd.exe --console"

Do you see any error? From a different command line window type "cm lrep", can you see the default repo? If not, review the server log (plasticd.log.txt) to find out the issue.

Alternatively you can send all the log you can find (plasticd.log.txt) to the Plastic SCM forums www.plasticscm.net the community and the Plastic SCM guys will help you on this.

Comment: I decided to use SqlServer. Got it all set up successfully. Thank you.